# adding excerpt projection to spring data rest repository causes stack overflow error

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

We are facing `StackoverflowError` when we enable an except projection on a REST repository. The entity is question has two associations, a `@ManyToOne` with one `Venue` entity that has to be included inline for all responses, and a `@OneToMany` with `Trainee` entity we always want to hide. The entity (relevant) snippet

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Workshop implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5516160437873476233L;

  private Long id;

  // omitted properties

  private Venue venue;

  private Set<Trainee> trainees;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "workshop_venue", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "workshop_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "venue_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
  public Venue getVenue() {
    return venue;
  }

  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "workshop_trainees", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "workshiop_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "trainee_id", referencedColumnName = "email") })
  @RestResource(exported = false)
  @JsonIgnore
  public Set<Trainee> getTrainees() {
    return trainees;
  }

  // omitted getters/setters
}
```

when I add this Projection

```
@Projection(name = "default", types = { Workshop.class })
public interface InlineVenueProjection {

  String getName();

  Integer getSeatsAvailable();

  WorkshopType getWorkshopType();

  Date getDate();

  Venue getVenue();
}
```

and enable it in the repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "workshop", path = "workshops", excerptProjection = InlineVenueProjection.class)
public interface WorkshopRepository extends JpaRepository<Workshop, Long> {
// omitted methods
}
```

I get a stack overflow error in POST requests

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

and further in the stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync$ThreadLocalHoldCounter.initialValue(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:286)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync.tryReleaseShared(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.releaseShared(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1341)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.unlock(ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:881)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:352)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are getting Stack overflow exception is because I guess there is a bidirectional relationship defined between `Venue` (1-Many) and `Workshop` (Many-1). You can confirm my assumption.

When you try to serialize venue directly because of the relationship workshop is loaded and it has a reference to venue and hence the endless recursion.

**Solution**

To resolve this problem, Jackson has `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`.

**Workshop Class**

```
public class Workshop implements Serializable {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "workshop_venue", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "workshop_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "venue_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    @JsonManagedReference
    public Venue getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Venue Class**

```
public class Venue implements Serializable {
    ...

    @OneToMany
    @JsonBackReference
    public List<Workshop> getWorkshops() {
        return workshops;
    }

    ...
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if this works.

Comment: is there a way to get through this without using Bi-Directional relations? I am through the `StackoverflowError`  but now, inlining is even more complicated as it invariably shows `Workshops` when we fetch `Venue`, which is not a very good idea given our use case.

Comment: Try making the ```@OneToMany``` relationship lazy. So that when you fetch ```Venue.Workshops``` are not fetched. If that does not work, then use ```@JsonView``` to control the rendering of fields.